# Difficulty installing and compliling dada engine on OSX

Tags: macos, unix, compilation, makefile, nlp

I am trying to install Dada Engine. The readme can be found here:

https://github.com/orenmazor/Dada-Engine

I have run the install bash successfully and "sudo make". However, when I run "make install" as per the readme instructions, I get the following line:

> /bin/sh mkdirs.sh /usr/local/bin
>
> /bin/sh: mkdirs.sh: No such file or directory
>
> make: *** [/usr/local/bin] Error 127

Any advice on how to properly compile this program would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

just cloned this repo on OSX (version info

```
sw_vers  # to check OS version: gives

ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.10.5
BuildVersion:   14F1713
```

The following worked for me:

```
git clone https://github.com/..../Dada-Engine.git dada  # use proper repo address
cd dada  # change into dir
./configure  # configure
make  # compile
sudo make install # install
```

Hth.

Comment: I do all this and the compile finishes, dada doesn't crash, but also doesn't do anything.

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert happens to me too; on MacOS 10.14.3

Comment: @ArchyWilhes -- thanks for the comment above -- switching the Repo is really the key.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend having a look at [this git commit](https://github.com/essandess/Dada-Engine/commit/8a2e4056940a5f2955ec66eac7af6d76f61e8479) showing amendments made by [Steve Smith on Github](https://github.com/essandess) to the following files

```
+5,428 −1,213 configure
+2 −2  configure.in
+4 −1  src/dump.c
+4 −1  src/pb.c
+4 −0  src/resstack.c
+4 −1  src/rtn.c
+4 −0  src/strfunc.c
+9 −3  src/variables.c
```

which fixed platform-specific problems with macOS (the original source is written to run smoothly on most UNIX-like systems).

Looks like you need to do some type-casting for strings, set the right cpp location, `#include` additional libraries, etc, for it to work properly on macOS.

Re-made-and-built and tested on my MacOS 10.14.3 and it is working beautifully as contrary to not dumping any text out to my stdout after running `dada dada-1.03/scripts/pomo.pb` previously.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the install instruction from schluppeck (`./configure && make && make install`), but use the repo https://github.com/essandess/Dada-Engine/ and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to install a few dependencies before I could get the Dada Engine to compile on my Mac. I used homebrew to install the following:

```
brew install bison
brew install byacc
brew install flex
brew install texinfo
```

Then I could compile the dada engine from the GitHub repo:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

See it's working by running:

```
dada scripts/pomo.pb
```